# Is Python multiple arguments return syntax sugar?

Tags: python, programming-languages

There isn't a straight answer on web, so I thought I'll ask here.

When a Python function returns multiple values is this just a syntax sugar for returning a list of elements that gets destructured after it's returned?

Comment: It returns a tuple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's equivalent to returning a tuple, not a list.

The tuple may or may not get destructed depending on what the caller does with it.  If the caller keeps a reference to the tuple, it will continue to exist for as long as there are references to it.